# PDF of random variable containing fractional part $x=\{1/r\}$

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, asymptotics, fractional-part

What happens if we combine fractional part problems and randomness?

For a start here are two examples.

Let $r$ be a random variable with a given probability distribution function (PDF) $f(r)$ and define $x = \{1/r\}$ where $\{z\}$ is the fractional part of $z$.

For the two cases

(a) $f(r)=
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \quad \text{if}\hspace{2mm} 0\le r \le 1\\
    0 & \quad \text{elsewhere}
  \end{cases} $

(b) $f(r)=
  \begin{cases}
    \exp(-r) & \quad \text{if}\hspace{2mm} r\ge 0\\
    0 & \quad \text{elsewhere}
  \end{cases} $

calculate the PDF $h(x)$ of $x$ and the first two moments. Express the results in terms of known functions and constants as far as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start here with a self answer treating case (a). Maybe others join in. Case (b) is more challenging.

**1. General**

The PDF is given by the formula

$$h(x) = \int_{a}^b \delta (x-\{\frac{1}{r}\}) f(r) \,dr\tag{1}$$

Here $\delta(z)$ is the Dirac delta function and $a$ and $b$ are the limits of the integration region.

The procedure to deal with the fractional part was described in detail for instance in this example ([Closed form of integral over fractional part $\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right\}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905488/proof-of-closed-form-for-integral-over-fractional-part-int-01-x1-x-2))

Substituting $1/r\to y$ the integral becomes ($A = \frac{1}{a}, B=\frac{1}{b}$)

$$h(x) = \int_{B}^{A}\,dy\; \delta (x-\{y\}) f(\frac{1}{y})\frac{1}{y^2} \tag{2}$$

**2. Case (a)**

Here $f=1, A=\infty, B=1$, hence

$$h_{a}(x) =  \int_{1}^{\infty} \,dy \;\delta (x-\{y\}) \frac{1}{y^2} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\tag{a1}$$

where, setting $y=k+\xi$ whence $\{y\}=\xi$, the summands become

$$a_k = \int_{0}^1 \delta (x-\xi) \frac{1}{(k+\xi)^2} \,d\xi = \frac{\theta (1-x) \theta (x)}{(k+x)^2}\tag{a2}$$

The heaviside functions make $a_k=0$ for $x<0$ or $x>1$. We remember this and drop $\theta$ henceforth.

Performing the sum gives

$$h_{a}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+x)^2} = \psi ^{(1)}(x+1)\tag{a3}$$

Hence the PDF of $x=\{1/r\}$ for a flat Distribution of $r$ is given by a polygamma function. Vice versa we have obtained an interesting interpretation of $\psi ^{(1)}$.

The first few moments, defined as

$$\mu(q) = \int_0^1 x^q \psi ^{(1)}(x+1) \, dx$$

are given in the format $\{q,\mu(q)\}$ by

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1-\gamma  \\
 2 & \log (2 \pi)-\gamma -1 \\
 3 & \frac{1}{2} (\log (8)-12 \log (A)+3 \log (\pi )-2 \gamma -1) \\
 4 & \frac{1}{3} \left(\log (64)-36 \log (A)+6 \log (\pi )+\frac{9 \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}-3 \gamma -1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Here $A$ is Glaisher's constant, which satisfies the relation $\log(A) = \frac{1}{12} - \zeta'(-1)$

Notice that the nomalization is ok, the average (q=1) is the well known result for $\int_{0}^1 \{\frac{1}{x}\} \,dx$