# Double fractional part integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, fractional-part

Let $\{\}$ denote the fractional part, does the following integral have a closed form ?
 $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x\,y}\bigg\}^2dx\,dy$$

Comment: Probably duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875076/evaluating-int-01-cdots-int-01-bigl-frac1x-1-cdots-x-n-big?rq=1

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thank you for the update. I do not know that existed before already.

Answer (score 3):

This is an incomplete answer that only addresses the 1-dimensional case.

We split the integral into continuous pieces:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}^2 \mathrm{d}x
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}} \left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}^2 \mathrm{d}x \\\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}} \left( \frac{1}{x} - n\right)^2 \mathrm{d}x \\\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( n^2x - 2n \ln |x| - \frac{1}{x} \right)\biggr\rvert_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}} \\\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( n - 2n \ln \frac{1}{n} - n - \frac{n^2}{n+1} + 2n \ln \frac{1}{n+1} + n + 1 \right) \\\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 2n \ln \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{2n + 1}{n+1} \right)
\end{align}$$

With the aid of computer algebra, we obtain that this series converges to $$\ln (2\pi) - \gamma - 1$$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: (+1) and welcome to Math SE!

Comment: But notice the OP’s integral has a square there.

Comment: @Szeto Thanks, I just noticed and I'm working on a solution.

Comment: $\int_0^1 \left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}^2 \mathrm{d}x=-1-\gamma +\ln (2)+\ln (\pi )$ `:)`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk How did you arrive at that? Did you evaluate the emergent series using complex analysis?

Comment: @Fytch. I've used your answer exactly only added a square in integral.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Yes, I did that too and got $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 2n \ln \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{2n + 1}{n+1} \right)$ but I don't know how to evaluate this sum to get your answer. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: @Fytch .CAS helped me.

Comment: @Dears, to get the result of squared single variable integral you should use the Stirling formula